# Force Keycloak redirect to user's host address in docker

Tags: nginx, wildfly, keycloak

I have a docker running with two containers.

The first container has wildfly and nginx as reverse proxy and the second one has keycloak.

The keycloak container name is 'sso' which can be resolved to container's ip address.

In keycloak i made a realm with name 'sso'.

The configuration for authentication works, but when keycloak tries to redirect the user so the user can enter the credentials , it redirects the user to 'sso/auth/realm/sso/output-omitted' but sso doesn't exit outside of docker.

How i can force keycloak to redirect to user's requested host address ?

Here is the nginx.conf

```
http {

    upstream keycloak_server {
       server  sso:8080;
    }

    upstream wildfly_server {
       server  localhost:8080;
    }

        server {
            listen 80;
            location / {
                proxy_pass http://wildfly_server;
            }

            location /auth/ {
              proxy_pass http://keycloak_server;
              proxy_http_version 1.1;
              proxy_set_header Host               $host;
              proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
              proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
              proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
            }
        }
}
```

Here is the keycloak.json

```
{
    "realm-public-key": "",
    "realm": "sso",
    "auth-server-url": "http://sso/auth",
    "ssl-required": "none",
    "resource": "sso",
    "credentials": {
        "secret": ""
    },
    "use-resource-role-mappings": true,
    "enable-cors": true,
    "public-client": true
}
```